# Where can I find descriptions of Spring Boot metrics?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, monitoring, metrics

We have a Spring Boot (1.5.3) application that uses Micrometer.io and InfluxDB to collect metrics and Grafana to display them.

When I go through InfluxDB records I can see that it has values for the following metrics in it:

```
dataSource_connections_active
dataSource_connections_max
dataSource_connections_min
jvm_buffer_count
jvm_buffer_memory_used
jvm_buffer_total_capacity
jvm_classes_loaded
jvm_classes_unloaded
jvm_gc_live_data_size
jvm_gc_max_data_size
jvm_gc_memory_allocated
jvm_gc_memory_promoted
jvm_gc_pause
jvm_memory_committed
jvm_memory_max
jvm_memory_used
jvm_threads_daemon
jvm_threads_live
jvm_threads_peak
jvm_threads_states
logback_events
process_cpu_usage
process_files_max
process_files_open
process_start_time
process_uptime
request_duration
system_cpu_count
system_cpu_usage
system_load_average_1m
tomcat_global_error
tomcat_global_received
tomcat_global_request
tomcat_global_request_max
tomcat_global_sent
tomcat_sessions_active_current
tomcat_sessions_active_max
tomcat_sessions_alive_max
tomcat_sessions_created
tomcat_sessions_expired
tomcat_sessions_rejected
tomcat_threads_busy
tomcat_threads_config_max
tomcat_threads_current
```

I am not sure if these are Sprint Boot metrics or include some Micrometer magic but either case I am unable to find detailed description of these metrics, especially memory and GC related ones.

```
jvm_gc_live_data_size
jvm_gc_max_data_size
jvm_gc_memory_allocated
jvm_gc_memory_promoted
jvm_gc_pause
jvm_memory_committed
jvm_memory_max
jvm_memory_used
```

Somehow, Sprint Boot documentation provides no details and neither does Micrometer documentation.

Can anyone point me to somewhere where I can find detailed explanations for these metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the definition of these metrics in the micrometer source code: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer, with their name, description and base unit.

For instance, *jvm_memory_max* is defined here: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/48eb59d3b5cb5e4df7f35c0dfa323241f3cf2484/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmMemoryMetrics.java#L97

So *jvm_memory_max* is "The maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for memory management".

Comment: Could you help me find the unit for process_cpu_usage or system_cpu_usage in particular? I'm a bit confused by those two.

Comment: Uh, never mind, I finally found it! "This value is a double in the [0.0,1.0] interval", from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad(), which I got to by looking at the changes in https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/357

Comment: Thanks @DanielM, this really helps. I found everywhere and the descriptions is not clear.